# Consuming WCF using Retrofit Android, The Response Body is null and response code 405

Tags: android, json, wcf, retrofit

I have WCF Service that contains this method:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "GetListInvititionFiltered?StartPage={StartPage}&userID={userID}&subject={subject}&customerName={customerName}&country={country}&invitationType={invitationType}&productGroup={productGroup}&companyGroup={companyGroup}&marketingEngineer={marketingEngineer}&proposalEngineer={proposalEngineer}&fromDate={fromDate}&toDate={toDate}&closingDate={closingDate}&sDataSourse={sDataSourse}&sCatalog={sCatalog}")]
    string GetListInvititionFiltered(string StartPage, string userID, string subject, string customerName, string country, string invitationType,
        string productGroup, string companyGroup, string marketingEngineer, string proposalEngineer, string fromDate, string toDate, string closingDate, string sDataSourse, string sCatalog);
```

and when I call this method from Browser:

```
localhost:8080/AndroidWCFRestfull/AAPRestFullHttp.svc/GetListInvititionFiltered?StartPage=3&userID=104&subject=&customerName=&country=&invitationType=&productGroup=&companyGroup=&marketingEngineer=&proposalEngineer=&fromDate=01%2f02%2f2017&toDate=01%2f02%2f2017&closingDate=&sDataSourse=DB01-SRV&sCatalog=AAP
```

it Returns this JSON in the Browser:

```
"{\"invitationContainer\":{\"PagesCount\":\"3\",\"ListInvititionEntity\":[{\"Co_name\":\"UMM AL QURA CEMENT COMPANY\",\"In_invitation_id\":\"118680\",\"Has_document\":0,\"In_date\":\"1\/2\/2017 9:41:00 AM\",\"ClientName\":\"UMM AL QURA CEMENT COMPANY\",\"Type\":\"E\",\"ProductGroup\":\"LAB AND EDUCATION\",\"Subject\":\"Handheld Precise Colorimeter\",\"Stage\":\"NOT REGISTERED\",\"Countvalue\":0,\"BranchName\":\"Saudi Arabia\",\"IsSeen\":0,\"DocumentPath_Mobile\":\"\",\"DocumentName\":\"\",\"DocumentID\":0},{\"Co_name\":\"GULF CEMENT COMPANY\",\"In_invitation_id\":\"119690\",\"Has_document\":1,\"In_date\":\"1\/2\/2017 2:36:00 PM\",\"ClientName\":\"GULF CEMENT COMPANY\",\"Type\":\"E\",\"ProductGroup\":\"INSTRUMENTATION\",\"Subject\":\"HERMO COUPLE FTBIDT\",\"Stage\":\"NWO\",\"Countvalue\":0,\"BranchName\":\"UAE\",\"IsSeen\":0,\"DocumentPath_Mobile\":\"Invitation Documents\\\\UAE17-8-99-7-200D525136424CB4B8AD0EC6FB6E96FD.msg\",\"DocumentName\":\"NEW ENQUIRY---1000015936---THERMO COUPLE---SE16-739ALG05\",\"DocumentID\":75411},{\"Co_name\":\"KING HUSSEIN CANCER CENTER\",\"In_invitation_id\":\"118674\",\"Has_document\":1,\"In_date\":\"1\/2\/2017 9:20:00 AM\",\"ClientName\":\"KING HUSSEIN CANCER CENTER\",\"Type\":\"T\",\"ProductGroup\":\"LAB AND EDUCATION\",\"Subject\":\"lab miscellaneous supplies\",\"Stage\":\"NOT REGISTERED\",\"Countvalue\":0,\"BranchName\":\"JORDAN\",\"IsSeen\":0,\"DocumentPath_Mobile\":\"Invitation Documents\\\\JOT17-1-99-1-8DFFF7EF2771462B9E0A2F8516ED155E.pdf\",\"DocumentName\":\"14525\",\"DocumentID\":74400},{\"Co_name\":\"CITY CEMENT COMPANY\",\"In_invitation_id\":\"119687\",\"Has_document\":1,\"In_date\":\"1\/2\/2017 2:28:00 PM\",\"ClientName\":\"CITY CEMENT COMPANY\",\"Type\":\"E\",\"ProductGroup\":\"MATERIAL\",\"Subject\":\"Hardox Plate\",\"Stage\":\"NWO\",\"Countvalue\":0,\"BranchName\":\"Saudi Arabia\",\"IsSeen\":0,\"DocumentPath_Mobile\":\"Invitation Documents\\\\SAE17-5-99-5-B7CBAF310C0C4113806C0E139EAE9D9A.msg\",\"DocumentName\":\"FW  16 00896\",\"DocumentID\":75408},{\"Co_name\":\"TECTON LIMITED\",\"In_invitation_id\":\"118679\",\"Has_document\":1,\"In_date\":\"1\/2\/2017 9:38:00 AM\",\"ClientName\":\"TECTON LIMITED\",\"Type\":\"E\",\"ProductGroup\":\"FLOW\",\"Subject\":\"Upgrading of Mina Pumping Station at Silaa - Pumps\",\"Stage\":\"NOT REGISTERED\",\"Countvalue\":0,\"BranchName\":\"UAE\",\"IsSeen\":0,\"DocumentPath_Mobile\":\"Invitation Documents\\\\UAE17-1-99-1-73A1537833314E849804306E9542E422.msg\",\"DocumentName\":\"NEW ENQUIRY    Our Ref   SP17-001SVT99 (TECTON ENGINEERING \\u0026 CONSTRUCTION LLC SUPPLY OF PUMPS  )    \",\"DocumentID\":74405},{\"Co_name\":\"JORDAN BROMINE COMPANY\",\"In_invitation_id\":\"118676\",\"Has_document\":1,\"In_date\":\"1\/2\/2017 9:27:00 AM\",\"ClientName\":\"JORDAN BROMINE COMPANY\",\"Type\":\"E\",\"ProductGroup\":\"POWER TRANSMISSION EQUIPMENT\",\"Subject\":\"SUPPLY OF MOTOR \\u0026 GEAR BOX\",\"Stage\":\"NOT REGISTERED\",\"Countvalue\":0,\"BranchName\":\"JORDAN\",\"IsSeen\":0,\"DocumentPath_Mobile\":\"Invitation Documents\\\\JOE17-1-99-1-E7B5369AA747433AB0900E4748E94289.msg\",\"DocumentName\":\"FW  Rotary feeder inquiry\",\"DocumentID\":74398},{\"Co_name\":\"SALINE WATER CONVERSION CORPORATION\",\"In_invitation_id\":\"119678\",\"Has_document\":1,\"In_date\":\"1\/2\/2017 11:33:00 AM\",\"ClientName\":\"SALINE WATER CONVERSION CORPORATION\",\"Type\":\"E\",\"ProductGroup\":\"MATERIAL\",\"Subject\":\"SUPPLY OF WIRE\",\"Stage\":\"NWO\",\"Countvalue\":0,\"BranchName\":\"Saudi Arabia\",\"IsSeen\":0,\"DocumentPath_Mobile\":\"Invitation Documents\\\\SAE17-4-99-4-388BF4357F254111B80F8F3D43E4560A.msg\",\"DocumentName\":\"FW  RFQ # 1831992\",\"DocumentID\":75400}]}}"
```

I am trying to read this JSON from Android Application using Retrofit, Here's the interface for service methods:

```
public interface AAPRestfulEndPointInterface {

@POST("GetListInvititionFiltered")
Call<InvitationsContainer> GetListInvititionFiltered(@Query("StartPage") String StartPage,
                                                     @Query("userID") String userID,
                                                     @Query("subject") String subject,
                                                     @Query("customerName") String customerName,
                                                     @Query("country") String country,
                                                     @Query("invitationType") String invitationType,
                                                     @Query("productGroup") String productGroup,
                                                     @Query("companyGroup") String companyGroup,
                                                     @Query("marketingEngineer") String marketingEngineer,
                                                     @Query("proposalEngineer") String proposalEngineer,
                                                     @Query("fromDate") String fromDate,
                                                     @Query("toDate") String toDate,
                                                     @Query("closingDate") String closingDate,
                                                     @Query("sDataSourse") String sDataSourse,
                                                     @Query("sCatalog") String sCatalog);
```

And here's the code call for the service:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy")
            .create();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();

    AAPRestfulEndPointInterface service = retrofit.create(AAPRestfulEndPointInterface.class);


    final Call<InvitationsContainer> apiCall = service.GetListInvititionFiltered("1", "104", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "01/01/2017","01/02/2017", "", "DB01-SRV", "AAP");

    String url = apiCall.request().url().toString();
    Log.i("RETROFIT", url);

    apiCall.enqueue(new Callback<InvitationsContainer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<InvitationsContainer> call, Response<InvitationsContainer> response) {

            Log.i("RETROFIT", "onResponse Called");
            InvitationsContainer result = response.body();

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<InvitationsContainer> call, Throwable t) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Service Call Failure \n" + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("RETROFIT", t.getMessage());

        }
    });
```

The issue that the response object returned with null body and error code 405, can anyone help me with this ?

Here's the rawResponse:

> Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=405, message=Method Not Allowed, url=http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8181/AndroidWCFRestfull/AAPRestFullHttp.svc/GetListInvititionFiltered?StartPage=1&userID=104&subject=&customerName=&country=&invitationType=&productGroup=&companyGroup=&marketingEngineer=&proposalEngineer=&fromDate=01/01/2017&toDate=01/02/2017&closingDate=&sDataSourse=DB01-SRV&sCatalog=AAP}

Comment: @POST("/GetListInvititionFiltered") use backslash in your intarface.

Comment: I will check it but i put the backslash in the baseURL @Sorathiya Payal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your WCF service accepts only a `GET` request. But your `GetListInvititionFiltered` method in `AAPRestfulEndPointInterface` is declared as `POST`.

```
@POST("GetListInvititionFiltered")
Call<InvitationsContainer> GetListInvititionFiltered(..);
```

Change it to `GET` to remove the `Method Not Allowed` error.

```
@GET("GetListInvititionFiltered")
Call<InvitationsContainer> GetListInvititionFiltered(..);
```